# Inserting images to a multiple choice field in Google Forms using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I would like to create a poll in Google Forms where the users could vote on their favorite image. For this, I'd like to create a multiple choice question, where every choice is an image. Since the amount of images is large, I'm looking for a way to automate this process - creating a multiple choice question out of the images in a Google Drive folder.

I've examined the Google Forms API, as well as searched for similar questions, but I couldn't find any API that would let me do this programmatically using Apps Script.

I was wondering if anyone knows if this action **is** possible, and if so, how?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S96r8.png)

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve - the script constructs a form from images of trees that exist in a folder in my Google Drive.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Images can be inserted into a Google Form, and an image can be inserted with code with the `addImageItem()` method.  However, Google Form content can not be dynamically changed as someone is filling out the Form.  If that is what you want, then it can not be done.  You could add images to the Form with code in order to avoid lots of manual updating of the Form, before the Form is opened.  If you wanted multiple users to have the ***same*** Form open with different Image choices, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: You could create a different Form every time, but then you need to make sure that the person getting the Form is getting the correct Form.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope it clears it a bit.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope it clears it a bit.

Just to clarify - I'm not trying to dynamically alter a form. I'm trying to create a form from scratch through a script. What I want is to provide the script with a folder of images, and receive a form where each image is a choice the user can make.

Could you perhaps elaborate how 'addImageItem()' can be used? As far as I've seen it adds a different item to the form

Comment: The image can not be clicked on as an answer to a question.  You would need to have a different question and the person using the Form would need to know what answer went with what image.  You could create a Web App that would do what you want, which is more work.

Comment: Yes images can now be selected as options (manually).  As for using a script the only thing I found was .setChoices but looks like it only adds text, not sure how to add images but it might lead you in the right direction. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#